# AngularJS or Moment JS Get Date Range from Start and End Date from an Array of Date Ranges then Flatten into one array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

Based on example below, how do I get date ranges from these two arrays using AngularJS, Moment JS, or plain javascript and flatten it into one array of dates?

Essentially turn this array below:

```
    [["10,01,17", "10,03,17"], ["11,02,17" , "11,04,17" ]]
```

Into this flattened array of all dates included in the date range calculation:

```
    ["10,01,17", "10/02/17", "10,03,17", "11,02,17" , "11,03,17", "11/04/17"]
```

Comment: The conversion between the input & output array is not clear. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please share your code

Comment: @GuyYogev So first, return the date ranges for 10/01/17 to 10/03/17 and 11/02/17 to 11/04/17. That should return [ ["10,01,17", "10/02/17", "10,03,17"], [ "11,02,17" , "11,03,17", "11/04/17"] ]. Then flatten it into one array ["10,01,17", "10/02/17", "10,03,17", "11,02,17" , "11,03,17", "11/04/17"]

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect, but you can get the gist form that. [codepen](https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/GMLoJd?editors=1010)

```
const days = [['10/03/17', '10/01/17'], ["11/02/17" , "11/04/17" ]]

const daysdiff = (d1, d2) => moment(d2).diff(moment(d1), 'days')

const dayRange = (day, count) => {
  const res = []
  for(let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    res.push(moment(day).add(i, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  }
  return res
} 

const newDays = days.map((pair) => {
  const sorted = pair.sort();
  const diff = daysdiff(sorted[0], sorted[1])
  return dayRange(sorted[0], diff);
});

result = [...newDays[0], ...newDays[1]]
console.log(result)
```